# Session/Cookie Issue?

Tags: php, .htaccess, session, mod-rewrite, cookies

I am having a bit of difficulty with form tokens. I have a global file that i require at the top of all of the controllers.

```
/*
 *----------------------------------------------
 *  VERIFY FORM TOKENS
 *----------------------------------------------
 */    
if ($_POST) {
    // Define and Sanitize
    $formToken           = $sanitize->input($utilities->getVar('formToken', 'session'));
    $authenticityToken   = $sanitize->input($utilities->getVar('authenticityToken'));

    // Validate
    if ($authenticityToken !== $formToken) {   
        $errors[] = 'There was a token mismatch error submitting your form. Please try again.';     
    }
}  

// Generate Form Token
$formToken =  $forms->token();
$_SESSION['formToken'] = $formToken;
```

When echo'ing the vars out right after being declared they match. But when i check the db ( I save sessions to db ) every db refresh displays a new formtoken that was saved. I only call the `$forms->token();` class once this is what it looks like

```
class Forms {
    public __construct(){}
    function token() {
        $characters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789';
        $token      = '';

        for ($i = 0; $i < 60; $i++) {       $token .= $characters[ rand( 0, strlen( $characters ) - 1 ) ];       }

        $hash       = substr(str_shuffle($token), 0, 32);

        return $hash;
     }
}
```

I have been working on this issue for a while now, i am confused as to why this occurs. I am also using mod_rewrite in my .htaccess file. I read that rewrites affect sessions but all other session data is ok ( session login data etc. ) it is just these tokens that are giving me a hard time.

Comment: Why do you think you're only calling `$forms->token();` once? Take a look at your code, and explain that.

Comment: @developerwjk I forgot to add the class name, but i instantiate the class at the top of my global file ( included using an autoloader ) and i call that class and set var `$formToken` to the token that is returned by the function. I am not sure if i am doing this incorrectly. I am trying to convert from procedural to oop.

Comment: Presumably you call the first block of code every time the form is posted...yet `$forms->token();` is called right afterwards every time.  Either you're calling this thing a lot, or your code doesn't make sense.

Comment: The form token that is defined within `$_POST` is the var that is pulled from `$_SESSION[formToken]`, the authenticitytoken is the one that is taken from posted formToken. They are both defined and called upon post for verification. If they do not match an error is produced, the form is halted and a new formtoken is issue below the post check. If the form is posted and no errors occur then the form is completed, user is then redirected and a new formtoken is issued

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to wrap an else around where you generate the token.  As you have it, it looks like you get the token, then create a new one each time.

```
if ($_POST) 
{
    // Define and Sanitize
    $formToken           = $sanitize->input($utilities->getVar('formToken', 'session'));
    $authenticityToken   = $sanitize->input($utilities->getVar('authenticityToken'));

    // Validate
    if ($authenticityToken !== $formToken)
    {   
        $errors[] = 'There was a token mismatch error submitting your form. Please try again.';     
   //UPDATE: MAYBE PUT IT HERE TOO:
        $formToken =  $forms->token();
        $_SESSION['formToken'] = $formToken;
    }
}  
else
{
   //----putting in an else so this is not done again on POST--------
   // Generate Form Token
   $formToken =  $forms->token();
   $_SESSION['formToken'] = $formToken;
}
```

Comment: Still having same issue, also wouldn't this open the form up to csrf attacks since the hidden form token and the session would be the same in the event of an error and both could be editable. It is weird because when i delete all rewrites within htaccess i no longer have this issue.

Comment: @ICJ, Updated the answer. Maybe when there's a mismatch you need to create it again(?), but not always.